# É correto usar "ir-se embora"?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, verbos, expressões-idiomáticas

Como todo estudante de português, uma das primeiras coisas que me ensinaram foi que *ir embora* significa o que em espanhol se diz *irse*. Desde então eu tenho ouvido mais de uma vez *ir-se embora* em contextos informais. Será que *ir-se embora* é também correto, ou pelo menos aceitável? Ou pelo contrário, é malsoante? Existe essa forma em todos os dialetos?

Comment: "Vou-me embora" ou é um uso em que a pessoa se exige autocorreção o tempo todo para poder falar erudito; ou é alguém fazendo graça, querendo falar diferente.

Comment: Sim, é totalmente correto e aceitável. No Brasil, está em desuso, tendendo aos casos que o @AndréLyra citou. Em Portugal, já não sei.

Comment: Em Portugal apenas se "vou-me embora", qualquer outra forma será imediatamente notada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Ir embora*** e ***ir-se embora*** são igualmente corretos. Na minha experiência de falante nativo de Portugal, nenhum deles é mais formal ou coloquial que o outro; nem mais bem-sonante que o outro com uma ou duas exceções. ***Tu foste embora*** rola muito melhor que ***tu foste-te embora*** ― aquele *te-te* é chatinho de articular e não soa particularmente bem. Na prática, na fala relaxada em Portugal aquilo é simplesmente pronunciado como um duplo *t*, *fostt’ embora*, que mal se distingue de *fost’ embora*. ***Nós fomo-nos embora*** soa bem, mas dá mais trabalho a articular que ***nós fomos embora***. Já nas outras pessoas, o clítico articula-se muito bem. *Eu vou-me embora, ele vai-se embora, eles foram-se embora*, etc. rola muito bem: na fala o *me* e o *se* enfiam-se ali muito bem entre o verbo e *embora*. No caso da próclise (clítico ante do verbo; e.g. *não me vou embora*), a articulação é fácil e bem-sonante em todos os casos.

Com estas ideias eu fui ao Google ver se as frequências das várias frases confirmava a minha intuição: que o pessoal tenderia a evitar *foste-te embora, vamo-nos embora*, e *fomo-nos embora*. Confirma mais ou menos. Já que tive o trabalho de coligir aqueles números todos, ponho-os aqui para quem tiver curiosidade.

Alguns padrões que se observam. De uma maneira geral os portugueses são mais adeptos do clítico que os brasileiros. A exceção é no *eu vou-me* e *eu me vou*: estas formas são muito usadas quer por brasileiros quer por portugueses; é onde o clítico é mais usado. Depois aquilo que me levou a ir ver estes números. Realmente *tu foste-te embora* é pouco frequente; nomeadamente, em Portugal, muito menos que *tu te foste embora* ou *tu vais-te embora*, o que sugere que de facto aquele *te-te* afugenta o pessoal.

Com *nós*, o caso é mais complicado. O clítico é pouquíssimo usado, mas tanto o é após o verbo (onde dá trabalho) como antes do verbo (o que eu não estava à espera). Além disso com a locução pronominal *a gente*, semanticamente equivalente a nós, o clítico também é pouquíssimo usado, e aí a facilidade de articulação é a mesma que com *ele* (é *vai-se* em ambos os casos). Isto leva-me a crer que a razão do baixo uso do clítico com *nós* terá que ver com outras razões. Omitindo o *nós*, a frequência do uso do clítico antes do verbo aumenta em Portugal. Por exemplo *quando nos fomos embora* está a 66% de *quando fomos embora* (não está na tabela).

### Resultados da busca no Google

```
                         Portugal                        Brasil
                   Sem      % de “sem clítico”      Sem     % de “sem clítico”
                  clítico   ênclise  próclise     clítico   ênclise  próclise
Eu vou embora       136       110%      24%         142      163%      41%
Tu vais embora       32        97%      84%         105       19%      18%
Ele vai embora      129        64%      62%         285       40%      16%
A gente vai embora   20        30%       5%         260        2%       0%
Nós vamos embora    120        20%      13%         261        5%       1%
Eles vão embora     102        74%      51%         324        6%      11%

Eu fui embora        87        71%      51%         255       35%       7%
Tu foste embora      50        42%      74%          89       22%      22%
Ele foi embora      159        74%      52%         129       65%      23%
A gente foi embora    7        14%       0%         185        3%       0%
Nós fomos embora     81        10%       6%         217        1%       9%
Eles foram embora    99        77%      47%         306       14%       6%

Chave: Por exemplo, na primeira linha de Portugal, há 136 ocorrências sem clítico (“eu vou 
embora”); com clítico há 150 (110% de 136) ocorrências de ênclise (“eu vou-me embora”) e
32 (24% de 136) de próclise (“eu me vou embora”).
```